# store stock price in varible for different stocks in python

Tags: python

So i am running the below code as an example to get OHLC data for stocks that stock OHLC data as global

```
high = NULL
low = NULL
open = NULL
close = NULL

def get_stock_data(symbol):
    data = getdata.symbol
    
    
get_stock_data("TSLA")
```

my issue is every time i run that function to get different stocks OHLC data the previous data is remove example if i want to get OHLC data for TSLA and GOOGL using the function only GOOGL OHLC data is recorded

```
get_stock_data("TSLA")
```

is there a way to store OHLC data for different stocks without losing the previous stock OHLC data
get_stock_data("GOOGL")

Comment: You can use append function in a list to prevent that

Comment: `data = getdata.symbol` is not doing what you expect; that retrieves the attribute of `getdata` that is literally named `symbol`.  The variable of the same name has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Make data a list variable and append:

```
def get_stock_data(symbol):
    data.append(getdata.symbol)
```